# Automorphism group of octonions is closed in $O(7)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, automorphism-group, octonions

So far I have understood that the group of automorphisms of the octonions is a subgroup of $O(7)$. I want to understand how it is a Lie group using the lemma that closed subgroups of Lie groups again are Lie groups. How does one see that this is a closed subgroup of $O(7)$?

Comment: For starters, do you know why it's even a subgroup of $O(7)$ in the first place?

Comment: Any $K \in Aut(\mathbb{O})$ is the identity on the real part, which leaves us with $7$ remaining dimensions. But then I also know that $|Kx| = |x|$. So $K \in O(7)$? Is that alright?

Comment: Yep! Just so. Now, as a hint: consider, for each $x,y\in\mathbb{O}$, the map $f_{x,y}: O(7)\mapsto \mathbb{R}^8$ defined as $f_{x,y}(A)=A(xy)-A(x)A(y)$...

Comment: Thanks for your hint. $Aut(\mathbb{O}) = f^{-1}_{x,y}(0)$, showing that $Aut(\mathbb{O})$ is closed?

Comment: Basically — more specifically, it's the intersection of all of those.